# Preventing page refresh after cookie consent accepting in PHP

Tags: php

I just created a cookie consent banner for the website to accept cookies.
Below is my complete code.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['accept-cookies'])) {
        setcookie('accept-cookies', 'true', time() + 31556925);
        header('Location: unit.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <style>
                body {
                    margin: 0;
                }
                .cookie-banner {
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center;
                    background-color: #D4CFD3;
                    width: 100%;
                    position: fixed;
                    bottom: 2px;
                    left: 0;
                    font-size: 12px;
                }
                button {
                    background-color: #AEA9AD;
                    border: none;
                    color: #fff;
                    padding: 5px;
                    font-size: 12px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
                }
                button:hover {
                    cursor: pointer;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <?php
            if (!isset($_COOKIE['accept-cookies'])) {
        ?>
        <div class="cookie-banner">
            <div class="container">
                <p>This website uses cookies. By using this website you consent to our use of these cookies. For more information visit our <span><a href="#" >Privacy Policy</a>.</span>&nbsp;</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="?accept-cookies" class="button"><button>Accept!</button></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <p>This is a website</p>
    </body>   
</html>
```

It's working fine, but the page is getting refresh it's because of PHP header redirect used

```
header('Location: unit.php');
```

How can I prevent pages refreshing after clicking on the Accept button of the cookie consent banner? I want just the cookie banner to be invisible.

Please help how can I do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Why header('Location: unit.php'); has been added to the code?

Comment: if you remove that header('Location: unit.php'), its taking two clicks to accept the cookie consent. and also after two clicks its refreshing the page.

Comment: First reload is presumably `?accept-cookies` which will hit the `isset($_GET['accept-cookies'])` condition, set the cookie and redirect. You need to do that if setting/checking the cookies with PHP since it runs on the server, it won't *see* the cookie until you reload the page. You could just set the cookie and toggle the display of the banner using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep everything in one page you could update the php-block like so:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['accept-cookies'])) {
    setcookie('accept-cookies', 'true', time() + 31556925);
    exit;
}
?>
```

This will prevent the rest of the page from rendering (which is not needed if you don't want a page refresh)

After that change the link to something like this:

```
<button id="accept-cookies" class="button">Accept!</button>
```

Then you should use Javascript (example is jQuery) to create an Ajax call to accept the cookies and remove the cookie banner

```
$('#accept-cookies').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '?accept-cookies',
    }).done(function() {
        $('.cookie-banner').remove();
    });
});
```